# Download zip file with jquery from ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to know if it's possible to do an ajax post request to a specific url and receive in data a zip file in only on request? Or I have to send two requests... one, in order to have the url of the zip file inside the server which has been created and an another to download the zip file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The native answer is no!

But you can do like this.

Your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your-url-that-gives-zip-file.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        if(response.zip) {
            location.href = response.zip;
        }
    }
});
```

Your php file:

```
<?php

//Get your zip file code with and combine with http://youradress.com

$zipFile = 'http://youraddress.com/downloads/'.$zipFile;

echo json_encode(array('zip' => $zipFile));

?>
```

Comment: thxx man....u saved by day....been on it for about 2.5 hrs....thxx again

Answer (score 15):

Sure you can do this! But only new browsers support this.

```
var url = 'test.zip';
var filename = 'test.zip';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.onload = function() {
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
   link.download = filename;
   link.click();
};
request.send();
```

Comment: Will the browser have possibilities of crashing as the file get's up to some megabytes in size? Will the user see the download-progress? I guess he won't - if I get the solution right ...

Comment: @SimonSimCity check out [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library, that should give you some idea about size limits. You can track download progress via xhr progress event, see [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 3):

You cant download a file with ajax.

If you only want one request, then ditch the ajax and append a hidden iframe to the page, with the php file as its source.

This will limit you to a get request though.

eg:

```
$('#id').click(function(){

    $(body).append('<iframe style="display:none;" src="yourfile.php?key=value"></iframe>');

});
```