# Download entire folder from Version Control via TFS 2015 RestFul Apis

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops

Is there a way to get the download url for an entire folder from TFS 2015 Version Control using the RestFul apis?

I can get metadata about items via the `/_apis//tfvc/items/` api, but no `downloadUrl` property is available.

I can see the `downloadUrl` property for build artifacts via the `/_apis//build/builds/{buildNumber}/artifacts` api.

I could download every file in the folder via the GET api for that item, but that could require a lot of requests.

I am using api version 2.0.

Comment: Would you mind showing example how you downloaded folder with files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any download url for items/folders with currently Version Control API.

To get an entire folder, you can zip it and download it with the Rest Api with following format:

```
[Get] https://xxx/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/items?path=<Folder Path>&api-version=1.0
```

And add following in the request header: `Accept: application/zip`

Comment: Ah, I was missing `Accept: application/zip`. perfect thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way. I have asked another question here that you might fancy a crack at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611326/create-tfs-source-branch-using-visual-studio-online-tfs-2015-api

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT If there is no zip file in a folder and if I try to get that folder with the above request header, Will it download zip for that folder?

Comment: @Sonali Yes, you will get a zip file for that folder.

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT  I tried the same but no file gets downloaded. Here is sample request: `$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: instanceName + 'DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=' + path + '&api-version=' + apiversion,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + PAT),
                'Accept': 'application/zip'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });`

Comment: @Sonali Not familiar with ajax, but it seems that ajax does not support download file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676748/download-zip-file-with-jquery-from-ajax-post-request.

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT then which approach should I try?

Comment: @Eddie - MSFT C#.

Comment: @Sonali Then you can use the .Net Client Libraries here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet to download files with API more easily. Refer to this link for more details: https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/.

Comment: unable to download zip with node module.