# Create TFS Source Branch using Visual Studio Online / TFS 2015 Api

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-devops, tfvc

Does anyone know how to create a branch using the VSO Api. The documentation for [Branches](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/tfvc/branches) doesn't include a "create".

I have been experimenting with doing it via the [ChangeSet](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets) Api without much success.

This is TFVC, not Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API apparently does allow one to create branches.
The confusion is that people think that this would be a `PUT` operation on [the Branches endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/branches?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) of some kind.
It is not.

In the REST API, a branch is just one more kind of change that is checked in as part of a changeset.

It took me a long time to discover this, myself; and I was using the old SOAP API in the belief, shared by everyone else it appears from what I can find in Q&As on the WWW, that this wasn't part of the REST API.
Of course, using the SOAP API prohibits using .NET 5, because the assemblies only come for .NET Framework.
An abandonware API on an abandonware runtime is not a satisfactory way to talk to source control.  ☺

The *terrible* Azure DevOps documentation gives *no clue* as to this, except for 1 obscure not-even-a-complete-sentence hidden in a minor class: ["List of merge sources in case of rename or branch creation."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvcchange.mergesources?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_SourceControl_WebApi_TfvcChange_MergeSources)
The only other clue is what appears in the JSON, from a [get changeset changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changeset-changes?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1), that describes the changeset of an already-made branch.
The (also abandoned) [Azure DevOps sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Tfvc/ChangesetsSample.cs) does not contain examples for even deleting an item, let alone branching.

Changesets are checked in via [the changeset creation endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1).
The individual change is a [`TfvcChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#tfvcchange) in the changeset's list of changes where:

- the version control type (which is a set of flags) contains [the branch flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#versioncontrolchangetype); and
- the [merge source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#tfvcmergesource) for the change specifies the source item and the range of changeset numbers.

Branching an entire tree appears to be a matter of branching the directory *and* all of the files and directories in the directory.

In C♯ or PowerShell, this is a [`TfvcChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvcchange?view=azure-devops-dotnet) with a [`VersionControlChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.versioncontrolchangetype?view=azure-devops-dotnet) of `Branch`, in a [`TfvcChangeset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvcchangeset?view=azure-devops-dotnet) passed to [`TfvcHttpClientBase.CreateChangesetAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvchttpclientbase.createchangesetasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet).

Comment: I can't remember why on earth I asked this question but what a fantastic answer. Makes perfect sense. I hope someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

Just as what you see in "Branches" page, there isn't any way to create branch with the Rest API. And mostly, you can only read/get the information with the Version Control API for now.

I would recommend you to use [Client Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx#clientapireference)  if you want to manage the Version Control programmatically. To create a branch, use the "CreateBranch()" method in [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't realise I could use that older client object model with TFS 2015.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT +1 Thanks for the information. Could I get any samples/demo to begin with? Any link would be appreciated