# How to download solution from Visual Studio Team Services programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need a way to download a source code from Visual Studio Team Services, basically I need a solution zipped, just as you can download it manually when I am on VSTS site.

What I have tried:

I've been through [VSTS API reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-team-project) but unfortunately I am failing to find what I need.

The workaround I can do is:

1. Issue a POST and retrieve [items batch](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items#multiple-items) that will return a list of all files from Main branch
2. Iterate through list and download files one by one

but I was hoping that there is a method that will give me a zip of the branch with all files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution using [.NET Client Libraries for VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples): Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, they as one could guess are wrapper around the VSTS REST API functionalities.

In order to retrieve zipped folder content from TFVC I am using method:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.TfvcHttpClient.GetItemsBatchZipAsync(TfvcItemRequestData
>   itemRequestData, Guid project)

Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MirzaMerdovic/afed2324d83bf94dcdf9296f2909c4e1) with complete code example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to download a file from source code:

### **Option1: Download a file by REST API.**

The detail steps you can refer [here](http://blog.devmatter.com/download-a-file-using-vsts-rest-apis/). Then you can compress the file as zip format.

### **Option2: Download a file by queue a build.**

You can add a build definition with **Archive Files** task and **Copy Files** task to zip a .sln file from source code to your local path. Settings for the two tasks as below:

**Archive Files task**

Root folder (or file) to archive: click `…` button to select the .sln file you want to download.

**Copy Files task**

Source Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Contents: `*.zip`

Target Folder: you can define a local path, such as `C:\a`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've updated my question with more details, I should've done that from the beginning.

Comment: ok, you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357671/download-entire-folder-from-version-control-via-tfs-2015-restful-apis, don't forget to use request header `Accept: application/zip`.