# Unable to download folder as zip via TFS 2015 RestFul Apis

Tags: node.js, tfs, zip, azure-devops, tfs-2015

This is a follow up question related to : [download-entire-folder-from-version-control-via-tfs-2015-restful-apis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357671/download-entire-folder-from-version-control-via-tfs-2015-restful-apis)

I was trying to implement a Rest solution with node for downloading the project folder as zip but the above solution seems to be not working. Can anyone help?

```
 var request = require('request');
        process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
        const options = {
            url: 'https://dev.azure.com/myproject/Project-TFS/_apis/tfvc/items?path=%24%2Project-TFS%2FTesting%2Fsrc&api-version=4.1',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/zip',
                'Authorization': 'Basic c2F1cmFqYWlzd2FsQGRlbG9pdHRlLmNvbMmc2YTVhczZnajdwbmVsNW5kYXA0dnNucm1qdTJya2J2eXpx'
            }
        };

        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
            alert('done');
            var output = "project.zip";
             if(err) throw err;
              fs.writeFile(output, body, function(err) {
                alert("file written!");
              });
     });
```

Comment: TFS 2015 not support `api-version=4.1`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I tried changing it to 1.0 as well as but no luck.

Comment: Which error do do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below REST APIs:

For Azure DevOps:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{ProjectName or ID}/_apis/tfvc/Items?path=%24%2Project-TFS%2FTesting%2Fsrc&%24format=zip&api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

For on-premise TFS 2015:

```
http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName or ID}/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContentZipped?repositoryId=&path=%24%2Project-TFS%2FTesting%2Fsrc
```