# Rails: Download zip file with jquery from ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to download a file as zip. I send ajax request and in response I want to send a zip file. But I get error. My ajax request as below

```
$( "#test-id" ).on( "click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<%= articles_download_path %>",
        dataType:"application/zip",
        success: function (result) {
           window.alert("success!!");
        },
        error: function (){
            window.alert("something wrong!");
        }
    });
});
```

and my download action

```
  def download    
    @articles = Article.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.zip{
        send_data(Article.zip_all_articles, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => 'articles.zip')
      }
    end    
  end
```

there is no error in my log but in my browser console gives response like this

```
PK����8dJH�/���
��������after upgrade 30.xlsx�W8\��u�0�(�A��Q��-!zDI0:3�^B�%����D��Ddt!z�������e�{�s�9��g
���W�k���I@H��H�Ǫ����V����c�n0'�����0��n�"|CF��Q��I&������C�ʘo�q��ke�XڑPJ�잝L5aNhlv�eU   V�D
ʟK�]����E�0Ё���s�9\�!��[RYqR%Ke�K���%5^�
```

and my log

```
Started GET "/articles/download?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-10 12:33:48 +0100
Processing by ArticlesController#download as */*
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
.
.
.
 Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data articles.zip (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 431ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

I think my ajax request for zip file is not correct format. But I could not find anything else by searching internet. How to fix this problem?

Comment: [Download Zip File From Ajax Post Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676748/download-zip-file-with-jquery-from-ajax-post-request)

Comment: Are you able to download the zip manually, by just loading   `articles_download_path` in your browser? This should tell you if the issue is in your Rails code or not.