# How to submit a form with custom variables via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a form which I use to perform login operations. It should do the following when clicked on the `submit` button.

1. Connect with `firebase` using javascript and authenticate the user.
2. Get the email of the of the current user.
3. submit the email to a `servlet` via `POST`, just like how submit works when you clicked on `submit` button.

Below is the code

```
function toggleSignIn() 
            {
                if (firebase.auth().currentUser) 
                {
                    // [START signout]
                    window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
                    //firebase.auth().signOut();
                    // [END signout]
                } else {
                    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    if (email.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter an email address.');
                        return;
                    }

                    if (password.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter a password.');
                        return;
                    }

                    // Sign in with email and pass.
                    // [START authwithemail]
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) 
                    {
                        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
                        alert(email);
                        window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
                    })

                    .catch(function(error) 
                    {
                        // Handle Errors here.
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') 
                        {
                            alert('Wrong password.');
                        } else {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                        }
                        console.log(error);
                        document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    });

                // [END authwithemail]
                }
                document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;

            }
```

The form

```
 <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control login-input" placeholder="username">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control login-input" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
                                        <i id="open" class="fa fa-eye fa-2x"></i>
                                        <i id="closed" class="fa fa-eye-slash fa-2x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" id="quickstart-sign-in" name="quickstart-sign-in" class="form-control btn btn-info btn-md login-bt" value="Login" onclick="toggleSignIn()">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center forgot">
                                        <a href="#">Forgot username</a> / <a href="#">password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

I can get authenticate the user via `firebase`, get the email of current user, but I can't submit the email to another servlet via `POST`. How can I do this?

**Update 1**

I updated my function according to @naga - elixir - jar. Below is the code

```
function toggleSignIn() 
{
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) 
    {
                    // [START signout]
                    //window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                    // [END signout]
                } else {
                    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    if (email.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter an email address.');
                        return;
                    }

                    if (password.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter a password.');
                        return;
                    }

                    // Sign in with email and pass.
                    // [START authwithemail]
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) 
                    {
                        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
                        alert(email);
                        // console.log(email) contains email
                        const options = {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                // set appropriate headers, assuming json here
                                //"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                 "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                            },
                            // form body, assuming json
                            //body: JSON.stringify(email)
                             body: `email=${email}` <-- x-www-form-urlencoded form
                        }
                        alert(email);
                        // url = your url
                        fetch(url, options)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => console.log(data))
      .                     catch(e => console.error(e))
                            window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
                    })

                    .catch(function(error) 
                    {
                        // Handle Errors here.
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') 
                        {
                            alert('Wrong password.');
                        } else {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                        }
                        console.log(error);
                        document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    });
                alert('hi');
                // [END authwithemail]
                }
                document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;

            }
```

Now I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at (index):69
    at e.g (promise.js:829)
    at Dt (promise.js:1168)
    at Rt (promise.js:1142)
    at pt.t.Yb (promise.js:1113)
    at dt (run.js:132)
```

For anyone interested in full answer, please see the below function

```
function toggleSignIn() 
{
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) 
    {
                    // [START signout]
                    //window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
                    alert('existing user');
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                    // [END signout]
                } else {
                    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    if (email.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter an email address.');
                        return;
                    }

                    if (password.length < 4) {
                        alert('Please enter a password.');
                        return;
                    }

                    // Sign in with email and pass.
                    // [START authwithemail]
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) 
                    {
                        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
                        alert(email);
                        // console.log(email) contains email
                        const options = {
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: 'LoginValidator',
                            headers: {
                                // set appropriate headers, assuming json here
                                //"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                 "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                            },
                            // form body, assuming json
                            //body: JSON.stringify(email)
                             body: `email=${email}`
                        }
                        alert(email);
                         url = 'LoginValidator'
                        fetch(url, options)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => console.log(data))
      .                     catch(e => console.error(e))
                            window.location.href = 'LoginValidator'
                    })

                    .catch(function(error) 
                    {
                        // Handle Errors here.
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') 
                        {
                            alert('Wrong password.');
                        } else {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                        }
                        console.log(error);
                        document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    });
                alert('hi');
                // [END authwithemail]
                }
                document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;

            }
```

Comment: after you've retrieved email, send `POST` request through `AJAX` or `fetch API` etc.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Thanks. I'm coming from Java background, no clear idea on Javascript. So can you show me how to do what you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

After retrieving data in your code below, send `fetch` POST:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function(firebaseUser) {
    var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
    // console.log(email) contains email
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        // set appropriate headers, assuming json here
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      // form body, assuming json
      body: JSON.stringify({ email })
      // body: `email=${email}` <-- x-www-form-urlencoded form
    }
    alert(email);
    // url = your url
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(e => console.error(e))
    window.location.href = 'LoadSellPendingApprovals'
})
```

More about [`fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: sorry, i deleted my former comment.  I need to have a "name" for the parameter being passed. How can I set the name?

Comment: you mean in the `fetch` call? as json or urlencoded?

Comment: updated answer for json body, using `object shorthand`

Comment: Please check my update. I am using `urlencoded` mechanism, and I got the error `ReferenceError: url is not defined`

Comment: you've to set the url variable, I just commented out because because it could be anywhere example, `const url = http://somewebsite.com/api`

Comment: Thanks, it worked with few changes. Probably changes to the sections you commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST form data to any server using a simple AJAX call. Please see the following links for further information on how to POST data using AJAX.

- [Submitting HTML form using Jquery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323360/submitting-html-form-using-jquery-ajax)
- [Simple POST request with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458984/simple-post-request-with-ajax)

Any other questions please let me know.